# How to show 2 Buttons with UNNotification macOS

Tags: swift, macos, notifications, action

I am delivering a `UNNotification` via `UNUserNotificationCenter`.

```swift
//AppDelegate
let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
```

```swift
// applicationDidFinishLaunching

// Add Action button to notification
let mountButton = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "test1", title: "Accept", options: .destructive)
let actionButton2 = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "test2", title: "Cancel", options: .destructive)
let notificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "content_added_notification", actions: [mountButton, actionButton2], intentIdentifiers: [])

notificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([notificationCategory])
```

```swift
func sendNotification(title: String, body: String = "") {
    
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    
    if body.isEmpty {
        content.body = body
    }

    content.subtitle = "subtitle title... "
    content.categoryIdentifier = "content_added_notification"
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(
        identifier: uuidString,
        content: content,
        trigger: trigger)
    
    
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error: Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError)
            
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine, except that `Actions` are not shown:
[image]

The Action Buttons only show up when hoovering over the notification, and to make it worse, both Buttons are grouped under an `Options` Button, that needs to be clicked:
[image]

According to the Apple Docs, the system should be able to show 2 Buttons:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcategory

> Categories can have associated actions, which define custom buttons the system displays for notifications of that category. When the system has unlimited space, the system displays up to 10 actions. When the system has limited space, the system displays at most two actions.

This does not match with pictures like the one below, so
**How can i make the notification appear like this:**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since macOS 11, the design of the notifications has been changed for unknown reasons. You must hover to make the actions visible, there is no way to get the far better old pre-macOS 11 layout.